# Geometry- Circle Theorem

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $BH\perp AD$, $DC\perp AB$, $AF\perp BD$ and $DE=EB$ then prove that $AG$ is the diameter of the circle.

[image]

My Attempt:

$\angle AHB=90$ and $\angle ACD=90$.
Let $BH$ and $CD$ intersects at $P$. Then, $\ ACPH$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Please, Help me to complete from here.

Comment: $PDGB$ is a parallelogram. You may use this to calculate $\angle ADG$.

Comment: Please elaborate,  How is $PDGB$ a parallelogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let's call $P$ the orthocenter. Now we are going to prove that the symmetric point of $P$ w.r.t $E$ (let's call him $N$) lies on the circumcircle.

The quadrilateral $PBND$ is a parallelogram because both diagonals cut themself in the midpoint. Then $\angle DPB =\angle DNB$ but we know that $\angle DPB=\angle A -180º$ and so $\angle DNB=\angle A-180º$. That give us the quadrilateral $ABND$ is cyclic and this circle is, of course, the circumcircle.

Once $N$ and $G$ lies on the same line and on the same circle then $N=G$ and then $PBGD$ is a parallelogram. Now we have that $BH \parallel DG$ and once $BH \perp AD$ then $DG \perp AD$ what give us that $AG$ is the diameter of the circle.

**P.S: Why $\angle DPB=\angle A -180º$?**

*In the triangle $AHB$ we have $\angle ABH = 90º-\angle A$ (becasue $\angle AHB =90º$).
Then at the triangle $CPB$ we have $\angle CPB =\angle A$ (because $\angle PCB=90$ and $\angle CBP = \angle ABH = 90º-\angle A$) and $\angle CPB + \angle DPB = 180º$.*

Comment: How is $E$ the mid point of $PG$?

Comment: It is a consequence of $N=G$. I built $N$ such that $E$ is the midpoint $PN$, after that I proved that $N$ lies on the circumcircle and as a consequence $N=G$ and then $E$ becames the mid point of $PG$.

Comment: @user354073: Is it clear now?

Comment: somehow. but not conpletely. Could you please explain in figure?

Comment: Is $G$ to be replaced by $N$?

Comment: @user354073: Yes, exactly!

Comment: In my circle, How do I show both the points $N$ and $G$?

Comment: You already have the point $G$ you don't need to show $N$ in your picture. Maybe should be good make another picture with just $N$ like I did and conclude that $N=G$ like I did.

Comment: Are $N$ and.  $G$ coincident points

Comment: Yes, they are! I recommend you take a time understanding the solution!

Comment: Then, why is $\angle DPB=\angle A - 180$?

Comment: N and G lies on the same line. What does this mean?

Comment: E must be proved as the midpoint of PN **before** one can claim (via "diagonals bisecting each other") that PBND is a parallelogram.

Comment: @Mick: Nope! I built $N$ beeing the symmetric point of $P$ w.r.t. $E$. It means that $E$ is, by definition, the midpoint of $PN$.

Comment: OK. I think you mean the following:- Let N and G be two points on PE extended such that PE = EN and G is on the circle ABC as given. Since (1) $\angle DNB = \angle DPB$ (because they are opposite angles of //gm PDNB); and (2) $\angle DGB = 180^0 - \angle DAB = \angle HPC =  \angle DPB$ (because of the cyclic quad AHPC and ADGB). From that, you conclude N is G.

Comment: @NeWtoN: are you good with that solution?

Comment: @Arnaldo, It is a bit confusing. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @NeWtoN: maybe there is but I don't know. Perhaps you can try understand this solution because it is very constructive.

Comment: @Arnaldo,  I did understand everything but I couldn't only understand two points

Comment: 1. How is PDGB a parallelogram and

Comment: 2. Why is E the mid point of PG?

Answer (score 0):

I have something close:

The point where the altitudes intersect is the orthocenter, lets call it $O$

I would like to define $G$ as the point of intersection of $OE$ and $AM$ and then show that that $G$ lies on the circle.

The point where the medians intersect is the centroid -- $N$
The center of the cirlce is the circumcenter -- $M$
[image]

$ME \parallel AF$  Not sure if I actually need this.  But $M$ is at the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of $ABC$

$O,N,M$ lie on a line called the Euler line

$ON:NM = 2:1$

$AN:NE = 2:1$

$N$ is also the centroid of $AGO$
$AO$ and $AE$ are medians of $AGO$
$ME$ is the midline of $AGO$

$AM = MG$

$G$ lies on the circle centered at $M.$

Comment: Could you please show me the figure for your proof? I could not get it from my figure.

Comment: @ Doug M, would you please give some time to explain this solution to me ?